# How to get total count of many to many field to a Django model?

Tags: python, django, model

This is a `Blog` model, how do I get the total count of `likes` from overall blog objects?

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    ...
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='likes',  blank=True, default=None)
```

In the template, I can use `user.likes.count` and it will return total like count of a single user but how I do I get total like count from all users.

Thank You

Comment: For a given `Blog` object, or all likes (so of all `User`s for all `Blog`s)?

Comment: all users for all blogs (All likes count)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the "through" model between `Blog` and `User` and count the number of objects of this through model with:

```
Blog.likes.through.objects.count()
```

Here `Blog` is the `Blog` *class*, not a single `Blog` *object*. If you thus pass a reference to the `Blog` class to the template, you can render this with:

```
{{ Blog.likes.through.objects.count }}
```

This is thus the total number of likes given by *all* `User`s on *all* `Blog`s.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).